# При отрисовке ListView наблюдается моргание строчек

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms

В Xamarin.Forms сделал на базе `MVVM` вывод данных из таблицы в `ListView`. Сборка под Андроид.

В `DataTemplate`:

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ContentView>
                            <ContentView.Resources>
                                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource LightGrayLabel}" TargetType="Label">
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding RowColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentView.Resources>
                            <Grid Padding="0" Margin="0" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="15">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.30*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding StockName.Image, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding StockName.Name, Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding BatchName, StringFormat='({0})'}" IsVisible="{Binding BatchVisible, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding LifeTimeManager.LifeTimeString, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                            <Span Text=" — "/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding ExpiryDate, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}{0:d}'}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Location, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding TotalLenValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                            <Span Text="("/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding LengthUnit, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            <Span Text=")"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LifeTimeManager.TimeToReadyString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding ProgressValue, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" ProgressColor="{Binding ProgressColor, Mode=OneWay}" IsVisible="{Binding ProgressVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                                <Label Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding LenghtValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            <Span Text="("/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding LengthUnit, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            <Span Text=") x "/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding WidthValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            <Span Text="("/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding LengthUnit, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            <Span Text=") "/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <Label Grid.Column="3"  Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding MaterialName, Mode=OneWay} " HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentView>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Моя задача только отображать данные, без их редактирования. Получается в модели перед отображением рассчитывается статус строки, и в зависимости от статуса изменятся ее цвет. Перерасчет статуса выполняется каждую секунду.

Проблема что у клиента на планшете наблюдается перерисовка с задержкой. Сначала весь ListView отрисовывается в едином цвете по умолчанию, а затем строки обновляются и раскрашиваются в свои цвета, через секунду-две такой эффект повторяется. При этом у себя проверил в дебаггере при отладке свойства в модели не обновляются, никаких изменений не вижу, а отрисовка в цвете по умолчанию вообще не выполняется ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем может быть причина такого поведения?

**Оптимизация:**

Сделал во ViewCell замену Grid на RelativeLayout, включил на ListView кэширование, сообразил что стиль прописал в шаблоне, вынес его на уровень ListView. Частота моргания уменьшилась, теперь вместо 1сек оно наблюдается раз в 5 секунд.

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MaterialStock}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CTStockList" RowHeight="34" 
                  SeparatorVisibility="None" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
            <ListView.Resources>
               <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource LightGrayLabel}" TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding RowColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <RelativeLayout>
                            <Image Source="{Binding StockName.Image, Mode=OneWay}" WidthRequest="16" HeightRequest="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding StockWithBatch, Mode=OneTime}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Constant=18}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.35,Constant=-18}"/>                                
                            <BoxView Color="{StaticResource BorderColor}" HeightRequest="1"
                                     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant=32}"
                                     RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant=17}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.35}"><!--Text="{Binding ExpireInfo, Mode=OneWay}"-->
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding LifeTimeManager.LifeTimeString, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <Span Text="{Binding ExpiryDate, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=' — {0:d}'}"/>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Location, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.35 , Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.35,Constant=-85}"/>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" 
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.7 , Constant=-60}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=80}">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding TotalLenValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <Span Text="{Binding LengthUnit, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='({0})'}"/>                                            
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Text="{Binding LifeTimeManager.TimeToReadyString, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.35 , Constant=15}"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant=17}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=100}"/>
                            <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding ProgressValue, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                         ProgressColor="{Binding ProgressColor, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                         IsVisible="{Binding ProgressVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"
                                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.35 , Constant=120}"
                                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant=17}"
                                         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.35,Constant=-100}"/> <!---->
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.70 , Constant=30}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.30, Constant=-30}">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding LenghtValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding LengthUnit, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='({0}) x '}"/>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding WidthValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding LengthUnit, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='({0})'}"/>                                            
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding MaterialName, Mode=OneWay} " HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.70 , Constant=30}"
                                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Constant=17}"
                                   RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.30, Constant=-30}"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Есть еще идеи как можно оптимизировать?

Comment: У Вас тут аж 2 проблемы. 1) видимо список сначала отображается, а потом с модели он обновляется с форматированиями. Стоит сделать первичное отображение программно после завершени настройки нужных цветов в модели.  2) уточните, есть ли отображение нераскрашеного списка при каждом обновлении или только при первичной загрузке? Если нет, то тут стоило бы искать способ обновлять не список целиком, а каждый отдельный элемент. При этом проверять условие: если цвет новый = старому -то не трогать эту строку.  Если Вы так и делаете, то ищите причину почему список обновляется целиком.

Comment: @V.March в том то и дело, что все обновляется через MVVM, т. е. каждый элемент связан со своей моделью и по всем правилам INFC обновляется оттуда. Такого чтобы была прорисовка не раскрашенного списка не вижу на свое планшете, сразу отрисовывается как положено и никаких задержек и перерисовок не заметно. Все это проявляется только на планшете клиента, где не хватает производительности. Каждую секунду считается обновление для свойств моделей, но при этом сами свойства изменяются крайне редко только поле с расчетным сроком годности постоянно. В свойствах есть проверка на изменение до уведомления.

Comment: @V.March Я не делаю никаких манипуляций с визуальным деревом, все работает через биндинг. И изменение свойств в модели не наблюдаю без видимых причин а значит полагаю что и список не должен сам перерисовываться. А у клиента визуально вижу, хотя ничего не делают на планшете и ListView рисуется в статике

Comment: Если входные данные не изменяются, но перерисовка идет, то найдите тот кусок кода который отвечает за ежесекундную проверку данных на изменение, и поищите нет ли в конце этого метода принудительной прорисовки или повторного биндинга данных.

Comment: Если планшет клиента можно подключить и запустить на нем дебагинг - то у Вас возможно будет шанс споймать те моменты, которые Ваш планшет возможно обрабатывает по другому. Вопрос многопоточности и проблемы связанные с нею на разных устройствах никто не отменял.

Comment: @V.March спасибо, буду экспериментировать

Comment: @V.March, а подскажите каким способом можно принудительно заставлять прорисовываться ListView? А то я даже не предполагаю чем можно это делать, а следовательно не понимаю что искать стоит) Пока только в коде вижу что все через изменение INPC обновляется, и события об изменениях расходятся крайне редко, а строки перерисовываются так будто у всего списка сбросили стиль, и по новой установили.

Comment: Я бы попробовал искать зависимость меняя извесные мне константы - например частоту опроса Модели или зпросов с сервера. К примеру, если поменять частоту проверки данных в модели, на 1 раз в 10 сек, то частота морганий так же изменится?

Comment: @V.March я отключал вообще обновление данных, это никак не повлияло на мограние((( Так что похоже дело не в том что модель обновляется постоянно. Моргание наблюдается даже если модель статичная и мы по списку не передвигаемся.